# Create Hyperlink in excel to open specific email Outlook by VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, hyperlink, outlook

I'm writing the VBA code in Outlook, to tracking all email information to 1 Excel file. 
For each email, I will put information in 1 row of Excel. And I want to add a Hyperlink in Excel file to open the corresponding Email.

My code looks like this:

```
Set objFD = objNS.Folders("dtk142@aaaa.com")
Set objToFD = objFD.Folders("Inbox")
For Each Msg In objToFD.Items
        '' mail information
        mDate = Msg.ReceivedTime
        mSubject = Msg.Subject
        mSender = Msg.SenderName
        mSAddress = Msg.SenderEmailAddress

        ' put to excel
        xlTmp.Sheets("RequestTracker").Cells(cntrow, 1).Value = cntID
        xlTmp.Sheets("RequestTracker").Cells(cntrow, 2).Value = mDate
        xlTmp.Sheets("RequestTracker").Cells(cntrow, 3).Value = "Email"
        xlTmp.Sheets("RequestTracker").Cells(cntrow, 5).Value = mSAddress
        xlTmp.Sheets("RequestTracker").Cells(cntrow, 7).Value = user
        xlTmp.Sheets("RequestTracker").Cells(cntrow, 11).Value = mSubject

        '' code to add hyperlink to the email item here

        cntrow = cntrow + 1
        cntID = cntID + 1
    Next
Next
```

Now I get stuck in creating hyperlink in excel to open corresponding Email. Please help me in this case. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple hyperlink will not allow to open a message in Outlook. Instead, you need to handle the hyperlink click (or button) and find a corresponding entry in Outlook. Properties shown on the Excel workbook don't allow to identify mail items uniquely. You can use the [EntryID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211865(v=office.11).aspx) value, but it can be changes when an item is moved to another store/folder in Outlook. Here is what MSDN states:

> A MAPI store provider assigns a unique ID string when an item is created in its store. Therefore, the EntryID property is not set for a Microsoft Outlook item until it is saved or sent. The EntryID changes when an item is moved into another store, for example, from your Inbox to a Microsoft Exchange Server public folder, or from one Personal Folders (.pst) file to another .pst file. Solutions should not depend on the EntryID property to be unique unless items will not be moved.

As a workaround you may add a user property to Outlook items with your own generated ID (see UserProperties.Add) and store it in the Excel row along with other human-readable properties.

Finally, you may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article helpful.

Comment: I just find out how to do this through this tips:
http://www.teamscope.com/support/faq.asp#gen-hyperlinks
There's require to change registry key, and add hyperlink to Excel through EntryID. 
Obviously that the EntryID may be changed when the mail is moved, but I'm ok with it.
Thanks for your answer.